# Why do I have two camels?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

Soon after cleansing Vah Naboris, I noticed its silhouette appeared in my HUD

[image: Said camels]

What does this icon mean and why does it say times two?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That icon is the power you got for cleansing Vah Naboris, Urbosa's Fury. The x2 means you have two uses left before it has to recharge. Use it by charging up an attack by holding down the Y button for a second (it has to be a substantial charge). It's great for dealing with crowds of enemies in a pinch!

Comment: It also is useful against a lot of bosses, stunning and doing massive damage.

Comment: I'm a bit confused though, isn't the icon yellow normally? EDIT: Ah nvm, only the Plus versions have individual colors. It's been ages since I played that game.

Answer (score 7):

This is [Urbosa's Fury](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Urbosa%27s_Fury), and the x2 indicates the number of charges remaining.

> "A destructive power born from the unbridled anger of the Champion Urbosa. Summons powerful lightning to the surrounding area. Trigger with a charge attack by holding (Y)."

The wiki doesn't have an image for it, but you can compare it to [Daruk's Protection](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Daruk%27s_Protection) and [Mipha's Grace](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Mipha%27s_Grace), which are also collected from Divine Beasts.